# opencv 3.1 dnn (caffe) module model import fail

Tags: caffe, opencv3.1, cudnn

environment:

OS: win 10

IDE: Visual Studio 2013

opencv: 3.1 master from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv

opencv_contrib: from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib

graphic card: nvidia GeForce 610M

CUDA:  tool kit v7.5 & cudnn is install

what I have done:

1. build the dll & lib by http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/tutorial_dnn_build.html
   and success
2. use the sample code (from http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html)with the caffe model & prototxt (download in current folder)  and build success

Question:
once I run my code. it will fail during import caffe model file

please point me out what wrong, thanks a lot....

the error is bellow:

---

[libprotobuf ERROR D:\openCV_root\opencv_contrib\modules\dnn\3rdparty\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:245] 
Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 6:15: Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "input_param".

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error 
(FAILED: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param).Failed to parse NetParameter file: ./bvlc_googlenet.prototxt)
 in cv::dnn::ReadNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie, file D:\openCV_root\opencv_contrib\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp, line 1101

D:\openCV_root\opencv_contrib\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1101: error: (-2) 
FAILED: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param).Failed to parse NetParameter file: ./bvlc_googlenet.prototxt

### in function cv::dnn::ReadNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie

[image]

Comment: I fine the root cause  from " https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3846 "


I should change to "old definition"


after fix  this, I will fail at " net.forward(); "


the error msg is  below:


OpenCV Error: Assertion failed 
(input.dims() == 4 && (input.type() == CV_32F || input.type() == CV_64F))
in cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::allocate, 
file D:\openCV_root\opencv_contrib\modules\dnn\src\layers\convolution_layer.cpp, line 89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DNN importer doesn't support some constructs of the caffe prototxt file. Nevertheless, you can modify and use it.

[Link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/935) to issue on github.
[Link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/files/1008491/deploy.txt) to modified prototxt.

Answer (score 1):

`build` [opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) and [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) with the tag `3.1.0` works for opencv dnn